# Is the title of an ECL file available via Core Service?

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, ecl, media-manager

In the CM GUI, when you view source on an ECL item, the xlink:title of the image is available:

[image]

But when you retrieve the same component via Core Service and view its Content, the xlink:title is gone:
[image]

I know this image is stored externally and that the ECL Service is the best place to get this kind of information, but for my needs the title would be enough for a report I'm writing and I was hoping that perhaps just this was stored in app data or cached in some other way I can get to via Core Service - or does the CM GUI make an ECL round trip to get this information every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get link title via Core Service in 8.5.

CME indeed make a round trip each time. It happens "inside" CME model service.

Comment: Thought so - thanks Yuri!

Comment: As Yuriy hinted: we are working on making it possible to retrieve this through the Core Service in Tridion Sites 9.6.